# Dividing main() function into separated functions

Tags: c++, function, code-organization, raylib

I just copied a very simple animation code from YouTube to learn how to do animations in raylib. But the whole code is written inside of the `main()` function. I want that to be organized and separated.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include "include/raylib.h"

int main()
{
    const int screenWidth = 1200;
    const int screenHeight = 800;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "2D Platformer");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    Texture2D run_sprite = LoadTexture("sprites/Fighter/Run.png");
    Rectangle source = {0.f, 0.f, (float)run_sprite.width / 8.0f, (float)run_sprite.height};
    Vector2 position = {0, screenHeight / 2};

    int frame = 0;
    float runningTime{};
    const float updateTime{1.f/12.f};

    while (WindowShouldClose() == false)
    {
        //UPDATE VARIABLES
        float deltaTime = GetFrameTime();
        runningTime += deltaTime;
        if (runningTime >= updateTime)
        {
            runningTime = 0.f;
            source.x = (float)frame * source.width;
            frame++;
            if (frame > 8)
            {
                frame = 0;
            }
        }


        //START DRAWING
        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
            DrawTextureRec(run_sprite, source, position, WHITE);
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}
```

I tried to divide it into these functions:

```cpp
Texture2D run_sprite;

void load_textures()
{
    run_sprite = LoadTexture("sprites/Fighter/Run.png");
}

int frame = 0;
float runningTime{};
const float updateTime{1.f/12.f};

Rectangle source = {0.f, 0.f, (float)run_sprite.width / 8.0f, (float)run_sprite.height};
void update_run_animation()
{
    runningTime += deltaTime;
    if (runningTime >= updateTime)
    {
        runningTime = 0.f;
        source.x = (float)frame * source.width;
        frame++;
        if (frame > 8)
        {
            frame = 0;
        }
    }
}

Vector2 position = {0, screenHeight / 2};
void render_run_animation()
{
    DrawTextureRec(run_sprite, source, position, WHITE);
}
```

And here is the updated version of code inside the `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
    const int screenWidth = 1200;
    const int screenHeight = 800;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "2D Platformer");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    load_textures();

    while (WindowShouldClose() == false)
    {
        update_run_animation();

        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
            render_run_animation();
        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
}
```

But when I run this, it's just creating a window and not drawing the texture.

I tried to get output from every single function's variable to debug it. The conclusion is when it comes to the `update_run_animation()` function, the `source.width` variable gives the default value which is 0.

I don't know what the problem is exactly, so I posted the whole code.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please don't split up the code into smaller snippets. Create one single [mre] to show us instead. And don't forget to show us when and where you define and initialize the `source` variable.

Comment: @273K Sorry I'm new to programming. Now I'm reading the link.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll edit it now.

Comment: The original and revised code is written in very C-like style, but it appears to be C++.  Choose *one* of these distinct languages, and remove the tag for the other.

Comment: @ubersmurf Your code does not contain a declaration for the variable `source`. Since this is the variable causing your issues this is a problem in your question.

Comment: Just from looking at the code, it's clear that you do not understand function parameters (your functions do not have them) or function return values (all your functions return `void`). Instead you are using global variables for all your function communication. You really should learn how to use functions properly first. Literally any C++ book will explain these basic concepts.

Comment: You never seem to define (create) or initialize the `source` variable, even though you use it.

Comment: @john Can you guide me? Where can I learn how the functions working and communicating with each other? Do you have any suggestions like a youtube channel or a website for learning c++ properly?

Comment: @ubersmurf Best is a good C++ book, but if you don't want to do that then https://www.learncpp.com/ is pretty good. To me youtube seems completely the wrong medium to be learning programming from.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I wrote the code incompletely. I edited it now. But this version does not work either. "source.width" and "source.height" is always 0. In my opinion source is getting the values before loading the texture. And I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of global variables happens *before* the `main` function even runs. So the values you use in the initialization of `source` (and `position`) will not be what you expect.

You need to explicitly initialize (assign to) those variables in the `main` function when the values they depend on are known.

Comment: Both of your solutions are fixing my problem. And I got it now. You answered it first like 1.5 minute earlier. So I'll flag you. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

One problem is here

```
Rectangle source = {0.f, 0.f, (float)run_sprite.width / 8.0f, (float)run_sprite.height};
```

because `source` is a global variable this code is executed before `load_textures` is called when it should be executed afterwards (like it is in the original program).

The simplest fix would seem to be to move the declaration to `main`

```
int main()
{
    ...
    load_textures();
    Rectangle source = {0.f, 0.f, (float)run_sprite.width / 8.0f, (float)run_sprite.height};
    ...
}
```

then pass the variable as a reference parameter to the `update_run_animation` function where it is needed

```
update_run_animation(source);
```

and make the corresponding change to that function

```
void render_run_animation(Rectangle& source)
{
    DrawTextureRec(run_sprite, source, position, WHITE);
}
```

Many other changes need to be made I think. In general don't use global variables.

This is all **completely** untested.

Comment: This is working! But flagged answer came like 1.5 minutes earlier. So sorry I can't flag you. But thank you so much for your time. Take care.